# is there a way to order a set to it compare to the original string to test if the string has a letter twice or all of the letters are unique

Tags: python, string, function, set, return

```
string = input()
def unique(string):
    if set(string) == string:
        return 'Unique'
    else:
        return 'Deja Vu'
unique(string)
```

the string is just a bunch of random letters, the purpose is to check if there are letters twice in the string. or all the letters are unique. now i'm getting 'Deja Vu' as return because the set is unordered and it's not matching to the original string.

input of "asd" should return 'unique'

input of "aasd" should return 'Deja Vu'

thanks a lot for the helpers

Comment: You can compare the length: `if len(set(string)) == len(string)`

Comment: @schwobaseggl what if i have multipe spaces in the string?

Comment: Then that's a different question and depends on whether you want to ignore spaces

Comment: @schwobaseggl if I have" a b c" as an input i'm getting dejavu because the length is not equal but the letters are unique